# read persian characters in a excel file with "xlwings"

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I use this code to get value of a cell in excel from "xlwings". Value of cell is a Persian word.

```
val = book.sheets[0].range('A1').current_region.value
```

The code works well for english characters. But I received the error below:

> charmap codec can't encode characters in position ... .

How to solve this?

Comment: Please open an issue and attach a sample workbook on Github: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues

Comment: I did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "print(val)" and checked the result in command prompt. I expected to see "?" marks for persian chars, but I saw the error. Now, I save the results in a List and see the result in the screenshot that provided by Felix Zumstein [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/932#issuecomment-417100657).